# 2014 Elantra. Put new battery in mechanic checked it over said solid car. Last night coming down I75 everything went out but motor. Now won't start?

Tags: battery, alternator, starter, fuse

2014 Elantra..Put a new battery in a few weeks ago and a mechanic checked everything and said it's a solid good car. Last night I was coming down I75 and everything shut off/went out but the motor kept running. Had no power steering, no radio, the speedometer was showed 80 mph but I was going like 20. When I got home and shut ignition off and tried to start it up but just clicked however the radio and things came on. Anybody have a clue what this might be? Has 150,000 miles

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me as though one of the connections at the battery isn't tight enough or hasn't made good connection. You can check the battery voltage using a multimeter to see if it is still good (should be above 12.5vdc at the posts). You could try disconnecting and reconnecting the battery at the main wires and see if it comes around.